# Accessing admin auth component from view in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'd like to display a link on my default.ctp page to an admin panel but only if the user is an admin.

I'm attempting to do something like this but nothing appears to be happening

```
//default.ctp
if (!empty($role) && ($role == 'admin')) { 
   link here
}
```

In my beforeFilter funciton in the appcontroller I have the following

```
$role = $this->Auth->user('role'); 
    if ($role == 'author' || $role == 'admin') { 
        $this->set('role', $role); 
    }
```

When I try print_r($admin) the admin role is displayed, but for whatever reason the if statement isn't working.

Comment: What is the value of $role in the view? debug($role);

Comment: print_r($role) displays admin.

Comment: then it seems like you are not actually pasting us your code, can't really help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about not actually pasting code. This is exactly what I have in my appController and view.

Comment: you would get a compilation error with `link` and `here` being not initialized. Also, how do you generate the link?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.role');
```

In the view file instead.

You will just read the value directly from the session instead of setting a new variable.

Comment: in most cases it's `'Auth.User.role_id'` (and not `'Auth.User.role'`)!

Comment: I agree, but here he stated "role" in his question!

Comment: indeed - might just be a spelling mistake from his side, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following code snippet in your AppController's beforeFilter() method:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
     $role = $this->Auth->user('role'); 
     if ($role == 'author' || $role == 'admin') { 
         $this->set('role', $role); 
     } 

     if($role == 'admin')
     {
         $this->set('is_admin', true);
     }
     else
     {
         $this->set('is_admin', false);
     }
    /***** your remaining code *******/
```

}

And in your view just use the following:

```
 if($is_admin)
 {
      $this->Html->link('Admin Link', 'controllers/view');
 }
```

Comment: parent::beforeFilter() should be there in your beforeFilter call.